# new link & controller produce Action Controller@index not defined error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am creating a backend page that i want to use to manage employee data (with laravel 5.8). I Added a link on a sidemenu blade that points to the employee overview page.

**Link:**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ action('Profiles\Controllers\EmployeeController@index') }}" 
    class="nav-link {{ Request::is('admin') ? 'active' : null }}">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Employees
    </a>
</li>
```

I also made a **controller** to fetch the data that i want to display, currently with dd() in the function.

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{

    public $model = CustomerLogin::class;
    protected $views = 'WebshopCustomers::customerslogins ';
    static $routes = ['index', 'create', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'];
    protected $datatableSelect = 'customer_logins';
    protected $datatableRelations = ['roles', 'permissions'];
    protected $datatableTrashed = true;
    protected $datatableRawColumns = ['email', 'deleted_at'];

    public function baseBreadcrumbs()
    {
        return [
            ['name' => 'Gebruikersbeheer']
        ];
    }

    public function index()
    {
        dd('test_index');

    }
}
```

After a reloaded the page shows the following error:

ErrorException (E_ERROR):
Action App\Modules\Profiles\Controllers\EmployeeController@index not defined.
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\shopname\app\Modules\Backend\Views\partials\sidebar-default.blade.php)

**Route:**
I googled this error and read advice to check if the route to the function existed (it didnt) so i added that.

```
 Route::get('/', 'EmployeeController@index')->name('employeeprofiles.index');
```

Changing the value of $namespace to null in the RouteServiceProvider was also mentioned, setting it to null did not change the current behavior of my code.

How can i correct this, what other things can i check?

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 5.8 in the RouteServiceProvider the namespace for routes was pointed to:

> App/Http/Controllers

in the new Laravel I think they removed it.

Now for your problem, you should check where is the namespace from RouteServiceProvider pointing too, and then adding extra 'directories' on it; e.g

> Route::get('/',
> 'App\Modules\Profiles\Controllers@index')->name('employeeprofiles.index');